# Unterschied zwischen schätzen, anerkennen und würdigen

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verb-usage

Könnte bitte jemand den Unterschied zwischen *schätzen, anerkennen* und *würdigen* erklären?

Comment: Schau doch bei Wiktionary nach: [schätzen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schätzen), [anerkennen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/anerkennen), [würdigen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/würdigen). Oder auch bei DWDS: [schätzen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/schätzen), [anerkennen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/anerkennen), [würdigen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/würdigen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best answer you can get is probably from a dictionary, because those words may have slightly to completely different meanings, depending on the context.
I'll give it a shot, though.

**Schätzen:**
Can either mean to evaluate something (e.g. a distance), to assume something, or to appreciate someone (usually in a positive context).

**Anerkennen:** Can be used to also express appreciation for something. It does not always have to be used in such a positive context, though. Also, it sounds more formal. Also, it can mean to simply acknowledge something (e.g. an independent nation by other nations)

**Würdigen:** Is used to express appreciation for something/someone, too. It has a very positive connotation in most of the cases and also sounds more formal than "schätzen" does.

However, if you could give a bit more context on what you are specifically looking for, you'd probably receive more fitting answers.

Comment: Danke das war sehr hilfreich die drei verben haben die Bedeutung( to appreciate) das war ein bisschen verwirrend .